# Visual Studio 2015 IDisposable pattern vs. FXCop Code Analysis

Tags: visual-studio-2015, idisposable, fxcop

Recently updated to Visual Studio 2015, and I tried using the built-in IDisposable implementation which generated the following code:

```
    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~MyClass() {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
```

Since my class does not contain unmanaged resources, following these instructions I did not override the finalizer, and in turn did not uncomment the GC.SuppressFinalize(this); line.

However, when I run code analysis, I get the following warning:

Warning CA1816  Change 'MyClass.Dispose()' to call 'GC.SuppressFinalize(object)'. This will prevent derived types that introduce a finalizer from needing to re-implement 'IDisposable' to call it.

So whose advice should I follow?  FXCop, or Visual Studio 2015's built-in IDisposable pattern?

Comment: There are many instances where built-in templates are contradicted by FxCop or StyleCop warnings. I've submitted feedback that they should dogfood the Cop tools and ship VS with compliant templates. The issue was closed. Anyhow, `GC.SupressFinalize(this);` is the right way to go.

Comment: Thanks, that's the option I went with.